# Trying to implement Newton's Method in order to find root. Not working, but why?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Newton's Method in order to find a root of an example function, but it doesn't work. Help? (Python) The values printed seem right-ish at first, then get out of hand.

class Newton_Method():

```
#Use Newton's Method in order to find the nth approximation of the root of f(x).
#Given: 
#    f(x) = 48x(1+x)^60 - (1+x)^60 + 1
#    f'(x) = 12(1+x)^59(244x-1)
#    x1 = 0.0076
#    x2 = x1 - (f(x1)/f'(x1))
x1 = 0.0076
x2 = None
f = 48*x1*(1+x1)**60 - (1+x1)**60 + 1
df = 12*(1+x1)**59*(244*x1-1)
n = int(raw_input('Enter the number of times to approximate the root: '))

for i in range(n):
    x2 = x1 - (f/df)
    print x2  #I print to check, but the values are all jacked up. :/
    x1 = x2
    print x1
```

Comment: IIRC, newton's method is an iterative approach...Meaning that you need to define `f` and `df` as *functions* -- You've defined them as constants.  Also, (and I haven't worked it out), but that derivative looks funky to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your equations, but the python syntax is like this:

```
def f(x):
    return 48 * x * (1 + x) ** 60 - (1 + x) ** 60 + 1

def df(x):
    return 12 * (1 + x) ** 59 * (244 * x - 1)

n = int(raw_input('Enter the number of times to approximate the root: '))
x = 0.0076
for i in range(n):
    x = x - f(x) / df(x)
    print x
```

Comment: Your comment has helped greatly; I didn't even think about introducing lambda into the code. I corrected it, and the program runs smoothly. Thank you so much!:)

Comment: Please don't write `variable = lambda ...`. Use a real function definition: `def variable(...):`. When you have an assignment like that, you have lost all the advantages of using `lambda` - a proper function definition is clearer, more idiomatic and more powerful.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: You're absolutely right. I wasn't thinking. Fixed.